# Assign values to variable names in lists

Tags: list-manipulation, variable

I hope somebody can help me in this (I guess) simple question: I have a list of variable names
`ls={w0,w1,w2}`
and another list of values
`v={0.1,0.2,0.3}`
What I'd like to do is to get the names of the variables from ls and assign to these variables the values in v, that is, to end up with variables w0,w1 and w2 that have the values `0.1`, `0.2` and `0.3`. I've tried things like
`ToExpression[ls[[1]]] =ToExpression[v[[1]]]`
but I keep getting messages of the form
`Set::write: Tag ToExpression in ToExpression[ω0] is Protected.` >>
Can anybody tell me of a simple way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: ls = {w0, w1, w2}; v = {0.1, 0.2, 0.3}; Evaluate@ls = v

Answer (score 14):

Use MapThread

```
MapThread[Set, {ls, v}]
```

Answer (score 2):

I like molekyla777's answer the best, but another way to do it is via `Evaluate`.  Initializing,

```
ClearAll[w0, w1, w2, v, ls];
ls = {w0, w1, w2};
v = {0.1, 0.2, 0.3};
```

This will pass the assignments onto the symbols inside of `ls`,

```
Evaluate[ls] = v;
{w0, w1, w2}
(* {0.1, 0.2, 0.3} *)
```

The reason this works is that `Set` has the attribute `HoldFirst`, so if we tried `ls=v`, then the `ls` is not evaluated to be `{w0, w1, w2}`.  Using `Evaluate` removes the `Hold`

Answer (score 0):

`Inner` works here! (`MapThread` is more general, but requires List wrapping)

```
Inner[Set, ls, v]
```

Answer (score -1):

I would try with

```
ToExpression[" ls[[1]]  = v[[1]] " ];
```

Comment: This does not give a value to `w0`, it just changes the value of `ls[[1]]`